# Nginx client prematurely closed connection meaning

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

I have 2 logs that happened in a few seconds apart.

```
2020/05/19 23:40:52 [info] 20979#20979: *47874 client prematurely closed connection while sending response to client, client: x.x.x.x, server: mymedia.com, request: "GET /dl-obb/data HTTP/1.1"
2020/05/19 23:40:45 [info] 20979#20979: *47873 client prematurely closed connection (104: Connection reset by peer) while sending response to client, client: x.x.x.x, server: mymedia.com, request: "GET /dl-obb/data HTTP/1.1"
```

Both of then are for 1 user and one obb file.
what is the differences between these 2 ? each one what means ? Thank you